# custom browser application need custom protocol handler

Tags: javascript, c#, browser

i have Software this software not run it on chrome and firfox only run it with IE 
So i order before 1 year ago programer to Custom application for my software
and its work but now firfox and Chrome update and my application not support new update if i want it to support new update i need to but new custom protocol handler or registry also insite the application 
For example 
Custom protocol is testch://
when i want to login my software i will use put javascript code like this

```
function Launchtestch() {
var url;

url = "testch://"+shost+"/testch?uid=";
```

this code will read my software like this

```
http://1.1.1.1/testch/v.asp?uid=testch
```

Can help me with that

Answer (score 0):

Yoı should add registery hçyou can find below link
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BMCVoiceStarter
{
    public class frmBrowser : Form
{
    private const string URLPrefix = "http://";

    private const string URLPrefixS = "https://";


    private IContainer components;

    private WebBrowser webBrowser1;

    private string voiceChatURL = string.Empty;

    private string uID = string.Empty;

    private string pass = string.Empty;

    private NotifyIcon m_notifyicon;

    private ContextMenu m_menu;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && this.components != null)
        {
            this.components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ComponentResourceManager componentResourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(frmBrowser));
        this.webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        base.SuspendLayout();
        this.webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.webBrowser1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new Size(20, 20);
        this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
        this.webBrowser1.Size = new Size(804, 536);
        this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
        base.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6f, 13f);
        base.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
        base.ClientSize = new Size(804, 536);
        base.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
        base.Icon = (Icon)componentResourceManager.GetObject("$this.Icon");
        base.Name = "frmBrowser";
        base.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Chat";
        base.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

    private void ParseCommandLineArguments()
    {
        string text = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            string[] array = text.Split(new char[]
            {
                ';'
            });
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                string text2 = array[i];
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2))
                {
                    string[] array2 = text2.Split(new char[]
                    {
                        '='
                    });
                    string a;
                    if (array2.Count<string>() == 2 && (a = array2[0]) != null)
                    {
                        if (!(a == "url"))
                        {
                            if (!(a == "uid"))
                            {
                                if (a == "pass")
                                {
                                    this.pass = array2[1];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.uID = array2[1];
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.voiceChatURL = array2[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateArguments()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.voiceChatURL))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("URL missing");
            return false;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.uID))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("uID missing");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool ValidateURL()
    {
        int num;
        int num2;
        if (this.voiceChatURL.CompareWildcard(string.Format("{0}*/*", "http://"), true))
        {
            num = this.voiceChatURL.IndexOf("http://") + "http://".Length;
            num2 = this.voiceChatURL.IndexOf('/', num);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!this.voiceChatURL.CompareWildcard(string.Format("{0}*/*", "https://"), true))
            {
                return true;
            }
            num = this.voiceChatURL.IndexOf("https://") + "http://".Length;
            num2 = this.voiceChatURL.IndexOf('/', num);
        }

        string arg = this.voiceChatURL.Substring(num, num2 - num);
        string text = Helper.HashData(string.Format("{0}:{1}", arg, "BMCVoiceStarter"));
        string key;
        switch (key = text)
        {
        case "BF05321D16974853B18C0F53DCC6FE27":
        case "98802C2BE4C213E35EFFAAD0C08FE0A6":
        case "C858839EB9D63ED19F056C7DFB58E435":
        case "C745078FA48F608992E61CE171F0E177":
        case "2E4992C259910BD4E2434992A0E7E75C":
        case "3ACB67FA5B46D7F8E4BF7978275D0C1A":
        case "83CF517BC614BF14265D2E1D6DC5D208":
        case "351BF60E1EA709BB07E629A705E99210":
        case "60BADFDD66FDD7AA42D2FA51C1137FDF":
        case "7FCC182B223DC096141278F3ADD255A9":
        case "ABC9082996C470F0ED45EB3D68ED243A":
        case "30F2F9DF800E220BB44484E0987F4633":
        case "4888F91CCDADA02F3A8CFD9610DB8884":
        case "B4FB3922D9376C50024261C79A9DB6CF":
        case "F71447ABE2296BBF380CCB999764F69F":
        case "623DAF13037BD7E2251E11C268F103B4":
        case "55D639CDFF739FDD23FD833552EBDCB1":
        case "1B2CA3C9F360A85A3A2C98F8518FDE0E":
        case "9A57B4B74A4D1FC3BF9E2D4D215C8C15":
        case "1DF439C58634981E45BD10D5ECCF8F91":
        case "C40B4B929A4DACFE250CDAA45C188045":
        case "CB9D4EABB87BE53B3568AC06E6C149F7":
        case "29A1B7B4AFB5FC599A999174D70BA7C1":
        case "CD31932F203A6925D012CEDF770AF825":
        case "7F49EDFCAC3595095DE2059C644CCB1B":
        case "DF4E754EF3BBB967A8186CC4F6E0787C":
        case "23E1BD4D36A19E5D1F4A9A7BC9C7B912":
        case "28310D07D32BA5B2AEF15D901E277033":
        case "32E2AF52F6520ADD026B88EC1CFE9F50":
        case "32298742427ABD179B0E38D8E7FA04F2":
        case "5587912CDB9A3E97227009A57F88C35D":
        case "3C8B6D4BBADEA2D56A33D273F35C29AF":
        case "A5FD7CF88F8D2302C58F064AF06AD442":
        case "DD335CA5276C295809F71B941797ED7A":
        case "4074808055C36A6C8192EB7465EE3EDE":
        case "AC13537983BF1D9B4C9D852354FEAB60":
        case "6BC78FD324D216A18B32B91070E6B4D8":
        case "888242F9545D1425075DF00B387787B1":
        case "EF234C011A8FE7DB9E3B64449A126AE8":
        case "3932EFDB37A48C9931261694601DBFE7":
        case "66906B1361572C93B227AB005F72522C":
        case "6AB63CF848C9D435A328B693906E7D19":
        case "097404C9369091073A6B1014D4067A46":
        case "0AE16C0CCDBEDE165E2E011779C12A29":
        case "0299FDFE5464B880A1DC714E28822748":
        case "0D2566BF3EBFFB7D06C79433BB9782B5":
        case "0E87C4EF5F72AADB217A4BACECFB23FC":
        case "00CF3DC266E928C2D146DE14DC8AFE15":
        case "03CFD8D8EB64BE4ACDB2DA37A3984C5C":
        case "09929CCCAC090633905AF967ADBAC522":
        case "04B834C9A36B2EBF2F710019678D9491":
        case "0936C5F080FFCA41A2C59495881A951B":
        case "03DD65E8FC6729A1A380033E5F621736":
        case "08743960D56E4DD914C914C91BA53814":
        case "0979EC98DEBAE2648A7AE80C66E4B5EF":
        case "0B0E9E669A3FE279967AB5F0EA9AA4E7":
        case "0F4D4419E146523371A181249DF76FA6":
        case "05FC88875E00082E2A69D3C86AB926D0":
        case "012C949D797C9319DBF992FCCD097798":
        case "0F8CFCECBA02C06ED94FC55F8976EB45":
        case "050513138F43867CC6947D865E87821C":
        case "06EB67267C75337F84450E39D30D3F3D":
        case "0A06E6A6441B393E25A6B41A88B2A527":
        case "080FC8C10A1596C600156144C51891DB":
        case "0416759211518EB0E2D0BD0BA8955EAA":
        case "0252E3D7B7ECD04A82C4D1C2C0A850B7":
        case "0D667DB00871C8C58D09A07EF4F6D6E0":
        case "04DAFB78979F174385F6158E9AD6CCA0":
        case "00F554033BF3407FE52D14ADB9BB22FD":
        case "06A0A36242886618971563A94D4CD2C5":
        case "0EEE67580F6570B180A2E03D0A92CC49":
        case "007780D3DD320FFC6F151487C42BD3C1":
        case "07401505EB323FF0E43B5AB0CFF431F7":
        case "1FD01B40B6D57C4DA394AD6110995013":
        case "1AE9DEF99779ED9D54F877CB5302A30F":
        case "0562911DEC37BA34044CB2CCB40B4D48":
        case "0A2607DB8A0F67252A78293C06A94DD2":
        case "050DB3CC1D74AF29AE92A1F74FC94DE2":
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void AddTrayIcon()
    {
        this.m_menu = new ContextMenu();
        this.m_menu.MenuItems.Add(0, new MenuItem("Restore", new EventHandler(this.Restore_Click)));
        this.m_menu.MenuItems.Add(1, new MenuItem("Exit", new EventHandler(this.Exit_Click)));
        this.m_notifyicon = new NotifyIcon();
        this.m_notifyicon.Text = "BMC Voice Application";
        this.m_notifyicon.Visible = true;
        this.m_notifyicon.Icon = new Icon(base.GetType(), "Main.ico");
        this.m_notifyicon.ContextMenu = this.m_menu;
        this.m_notifyicon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(this.Restore_Click);
    }

    private void RemoveTrayIcon()
    {
        if (this.m_notifyicon != null)
        {
            this.m_notifyicon.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected void Restore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Show();
        base.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        frmBrowser.SetForegroundWindow(base.Handle.ToInt32());
    }

    protected void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Close();
    }

    public frmBrowser()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        base.Resize += new EventHandler(this.frmBrowser_Resize);
        base.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(this.frmBrowser_FormClosed);
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(this.webBrowser1_DocumentTitleChanged);
        this.ParseCommandLineArguments();
        if (!this.ValidateArguments() || !this.ValidateURL())
        {
            base.Load += delegate(object s, EventArgs e)
            {
                base.Close();
            };
            return;
        }
        this.AddTrayIcon();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.pass))
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate(string.Format("{0}?uid={1}", this.voiceChatURL, this.uID));
            return;
        }
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(string.Format("{0}?uid={1}&pass={2}", this.voiceChatURL, this.uID, Helper.EncodeTo64(this.pass)));
    }

    private void frmBrowser_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RemoveTrayIcon();
    }

    private void frmBrowser_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (base.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            base.Hide();
        }
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = this.webBrowser1.DocumentTitle;
    }

}
}
```

this is the code